# Parse Xml file and map to columns in SharePoint list

Tags: xml, sharepoint-online, xmldocument, xmlreader

I have an XML file in the below format.
I have sharepoint list created with the columns URL, Title etc. I need to insert the values from XML to SP list using CSOM. Can someone suggest a code.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<Sites>

-<Site xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<Url>https://ccepdev.sharepoint.com/sites/CCEP</Url>

<Title>CCEP</Title>

<WebTemplateTitle>Team site (classic experience)</WebTemplateTitle>

<WebTemplateName>STS#0</WebTemplateName>

<CreatedDate>2019-04-15T16:59:31+05:30</CreatedDate>

<LastItemModifiedDate>2019-04-23T13:26:55+05:30</LastItemModifiedDate>

<HasUniquePermissionValue>true</HasUniquePermissionValue>

<Description/>

<SiteCollectionUrl>https://ccepdev.sharepoint.com/sites/CCEP</SiteCollectionUrl>

<IsDeprecated>false</IsDeprecated>

<SubWebUrls/>

<ServerRelativeUrl>/sites/CCEP</ServerRelativeUrl>

<IsPublishingFeatureActivated>false</IsPublishingFeatureActivated>

<Language>1033</Language>

<IsNonDefaultMasterPage>false</IsNonDefaultMasterPage>

<CustomMasterPageUrl>/sites/CCEP/_catalogs/masterpage/seattle.master</CustomMasterPageUrl>

<MasterPageUrl>/sites/CCEP/_catalogs/masterpage/seattle.master</MasterPageUrl>

</Site>

</Sites>

---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I have the XMl in below format. How can we modify the code accordingly?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<log>
-<entry stage="Write" severity="Informational" date="2019-04-24T09:59:34.0355446Z">

<rec>10</rec>

<context>Processing Notes Document</context>

<unid>18877D1F2CF28BBC4725711C0033ECCF</unid>

<documentUrl>notes:///4825833200162448/0/18877d1f2cf28bbc4725711c0033eccf</documentUrl>

<message>18877d1f2cf28bbc4725711c0033eccf</message>

<stackTrace/>

</entry>
</log>

Comment: -<entry stage="Write" severity="Informational" date="2019-04-24T09:59:34.0355446Z">

<rec>10</rec>

<context>Processing Notes Document</context>

<unid>18877D1F2CF28BBC4725711C0033ECCF</unid>

<documentUrl>notes:///4825833200162448/0/18877d1f2cf28bbc4725711c0033eccf</documentUrl>

<message>18877d1f2cf28bbc4725711c0033eccf</message>

<stackTrace/>

</entry>

Answer (score 0):

Use Linq to XML to select node/attribute and then add to SharePoint by CSOM.

```
XElement xmlFile = XElement.Load(@"C:\Lee\SiteData.xml");

            var data = from item in xmlFile.Descendants("Site")
                                          select new
                                          {
                                              ID = item.Element("Url").Value,
                                              Title = item.Element("Title").Value,
                                              WebTemplateTitle= item.Element("WebTemplateTitle").Value
                                              //more 
                                          };


using (var context = new ClientContext("https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/Developer"))
            {                 
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                string password = "password";
                SecureString sec_pass = new SecureString();
                Array.ForEach(password.ToArray(), sec_pass.AppendChar);
                sec_pass.MakeReadOnly();
                context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("lee@tenant.onmicrosoft.com", sec_pass);


                SP.List oList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("listtitle");
                ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
                ListItem oListItem = oList.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);
                oListItem["Title"] = data.Title;                

                oListItem.Update();

                context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```